# Is there way I could upload a image without deleting the old image onto the firebase storage?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter

Im able to upload image and giving it a `name.jpg` then passing it to object name to be upload to the firebase. The problem is that only one picture is able to stay in the firebase. I want to be able to store multiple pictures.

I was not able to find way to change this. This code below is functionality of accessing the gallery or you can make it access the camera. Im able to send a picture to the firebase storage but store only one image and the previous one gets deleted. I don't want that. I want to be able store pictures without deleting previous picture.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File sampleImage;

  Future getImage() async {
    var tempImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      sampleImage = tempImage;
    });
  }




RaisedButton( 
            elevation: 7.0,
            child: Text('Upload'),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {
              final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =     FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('myimage.jpg');
              final StorageUploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(sampleImage);

            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few options. First of yes, any time you upload a file with the same name to the same directory in Firebase storage, it replaces the file that exists. There are really two options:

1. Change the file name in some way. A pretty easy way to do this would be to append the current date time to the image i.e. `"myimage_" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime() + ".jpg"`. You may have to import the Calendar utility here.
2. Add the image to a unique directory. On Firebase storage you can create directories much like on a local computer. To do so, in the child method parameter, you pass a URI style string i.e. `imgName = images/uniqueidentifier/myimage.jpg` to save a file 'myimage.jpg' to the path 'images/uniqueidentifier.'

You may want to save these image paths somewhere such as the firestore to make it easier to interact with later.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files further reading.

Comment: Thank you so much. Im going to try this.